# Getting rid of "(blank)" in pivot table in Power Query

Tags: filter, powerbi, format, powerquery

I have a query that assigns a category based on the number of weeks that have the same frequency. Each row is a participant, a date (start_of_week), and a number that represents the frequency.

[image]

I am then adding this information to another table called Participants. For each frequency category, I'm counting the number of times that participant has a week with that frequency.  To do that I use this formula:

```
=CALCULATE(COUNT( Weekly_Freq_Usage[Participant_ID]),Weekly_Freq_Usage[WeeklyUsage_Cat]="1",FILTER(Weekly_Freq_Usage,Weekly_Freq_Usage[Participant_ID]=Participants[Participant_ID]))
```

and the columns in that table look like this:

[image]

The problem is when I create a "Pivot Table" - which is rows only - when a participant doesn't have any weeks at that frequency it shows "(blank)".

[image]

I'm guessing there's some way to embed some type of if statement to return a zero or null but I only have moderate experience and that formula is tapping out my skill level.

I've tried simple formatting, changing the field from a whole number to text, and I tried adding some kind of if statement but it was a mess and only resulted in errors.  I also tried using the PivotTable Options "for empty cells show 0" but that didn't change anything.  The value that appears in that table can be null or 0.